# ConTeXt: Is there a way to show the \part heading?

Tags: sectioning, context, context-mkiv

I’m new to ConTeXt, and noticed that `\part{Some title}` (and neither `\start part[title={Some title}]…\stoppart`) will produce and output (besides an empty page with footer and header). Nevertheless, other settings as `\setuphead[part][footer=empty]` will have an effect on that page, but I can’t get to display the number nor the title of the `\part`.

I remember had read in some introductory doc (not sure which one) that this was because the `\part` command required mostly a special (visual) setup from the editor, but don’t know how this can be achieved (and said doc didn’t go into that). Does anybody know how?

Comment: You can show the content of `\part` with `\setuphead[part][placehead=yes]`.